# How to ignore parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When use React, I need to override componentDidUpdate method in Component classes.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(prevProps)
}
```

In this case, IDE reports `Incompatible override, should have signature '(prevProps: Readonly<P>, prevState: Readonly<S>, snapshot?: SS): void'`,so I switched to

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
      console.log(prevProps);
}
```

Then IDE reports `prevState is defined but never used`.In fact I don't need prevState in overrided method.So can I ignore prevState parameter?

Comment: This sounds like a linting issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using typescript. And using like below will obviously throw an error:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(prevProps)
}
```

You should have:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<P>) {
    console.log(prevProps)
}
```

If you don't use anything,

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log('did update')
}
```

Then it will not throw you an error.